How to show all X values on the chart C#?
I need to show a value on each month. It should look like this

I tried the next code
var months = new string[]{"January", "February", "March"};//till December
var values = new int []{1, 2, 3, 4};
for (int i = 0; i < months.Length; i++)
{
    DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
    dp.AxisLabel = months[i].ToString();
    dp.YValues = new double[] { values[i] };

    chartProfit.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);
}

And on the screen I got this

How to make my chart show all x values?
And adding chartProfit.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault().AxisX.Interval = 1; doesn't help

What's the contents of months? If it only contains one entry, you'll get one bar.

Your code also suggests you have data separated in two arrays. You might want to consider having one array of a datamodel that has respective properties of monthname and value.

If you always want to show all months Jan-Dec, then hardcode missing entries to value 0.0 and add them to the series.


dp doesn't have an x-value, just a Label. 2) make sure you add the x-values as numbers not strings!!!. If you do so you can use a format instead of labels..


@Fildor I added code for months and values. I'm just wondering why it shows only one value

You need to, as I wrote, add the XValues explicitly and as numbers. As it stands they all are 0. Also try to remove the intevall and leave the automatic interval on!. The bar we see has a vertiacal value of 12, so it is the last one.  Use the debugger to inspect all datapaonts and all their values!!!

I solved this problem adding.
dp.XValue = i;

So XValues should be added explicitly as numbers
